# Jquery files not getting loaded on frontend after upgrade

Tags: magento2, upgrade, jquery-ui

I have upgraded my site from 2.2.6 to 2.3.2.
After the upgrade when i load the frontend, and open Network tab in inspect element, i see that only jquery.js file is being called, no other js files like jquery-ui.js is getting loaded. What is the issue?

[image]

Comment: Hello, can you kindly remove 'jquery' from the filter & take a look ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove 'jquery' text from the browser filter.